# .htaccess for redirecting an URL with hashtag

Tags: apache-httpd, url, mod-rewrite

I have urls which I need to redirect to another URL. The issue is that the source URLs contain # character.

```
source url: http://www.wawa.com/fr/#/creations/eclairs
redirect to : http://www.wawa.fr/fr/patisseries-1

source url: http://www.wawa.com/fr/#/home
Redirect to : http://www.wawa.fr/fr/
```

I have tried to use redirect 301 but it doesn't seem to work: (just for urls with #). See my code below-

```
Redirect 301 /fr/#/creations/eclairs http://www.wawa.fr/fr/patisseries-1
```

Comment: The `#` character isn't part of the URL seen by the server; it indicates a _tag_ inside the current page.    eg `http://foo/bar#baz` means _request `http://foo/bar` and then jump to tag `baz`_ .  The best you can redirect on the server is the whole `http://wawa.com/fr/` page.  Otherwise you'll need to write a html page that does _client side redirection_ via javascript.

Comment: I can't redirect the whole page. as there are several # that need redirecting to other pages.
I read somewhere that i can use RewriteRule.
But I don't know what regex to use to interprete #

Comment: As Stephen Harris says, you cannot do this on the server. Apache httpd never sees a '#' in the URL, because the browsers interpret that part. They never send it to Apache (unless it is encoded). So it doesn't matter what regex you use.